# Two simultaneous prefix keys in Tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Can i have two simultaneous prefix keys?
I can `set -g prefix C-a` in my `~/.tmux.conf` to overwrite the default prefix key.   I've experimented a little with the config (C-a,C-b...) and I've searched a little, but not found an answer so far.

I can think of potential reasons why this may be a bad idea, but I think I'm okay with them, unless i'm being especially naive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

`set-option -g prefix2 C-a`

Here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148449/multiple-tmux-prefix-key-combos